# How can i create an internal ELB with security groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

Im using an internal ELB right now. Its only accessible from inside my VPCs which is good.

But now I want to add a security group to allow an external network access to the ELB. I could use a proxy server but I suspect there is a better way.

Can I create a public ELB and use security group to only allow it access to my VPC networks without hardcoding IPs? Is there a variable/placeholder i can use in a security group that says "all my connected vpcs"? Because then i could do that and just add an sg for that external network.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an ELB and assign it a security group, then assign all resources you wish the ELB to be able to access a second security group, with a rule permitting access from the ELB's source security group.

See the [ELB section of this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-other-instances)

Comment: so is that security group just empty? I would create a security group with no rules?

Comment: also, security groups are not cross region

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign access by specifying `vpc-` (how you might expect to, similar to being able to allow access based on other security groups by specifying the sg number, `sg-...`, under *Source:*).

However, it's easy enough to just put the subnets of your VPCs you want to allow access to and from. If your VPC is assigned the subnet of `10.10.0.0/16`, specify that as a Source.

If you *really* want to have a single security group defined on your ELB for all of your VPCs, just create a stand-alone security group allowing access from all of your VPCs called `vpc-access` or something, and then assign *that* `sg-...` to your ELB *Source:* list.